# How to set email as urgent in Lotus Notes using VBA?

Tags: api, vba, lotus-notes

I'm hoping someone can give me an example of how to set an email as "urgent" in Lotus Notes using VBA.

Is there a VBA API library for Lotus Notes that would do this?

Comment: Perhaps, [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/44116-lotus-notes-mail-visual-basic-applications.html) will be of use?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the code already for sending an email via VBA, you just need to set the importance item on the mail document before sending:

```
maildoc.Importance = "1"  '1 = high, 2 = normal, 3 = low
```